# Can Asterisk Send Data Along with a Transfer?

Tags: asterisk

I'd like to use Transfer() to send a call from one Asterisk box over to another. But I need to send an ID number along with it and do some processing on that number on the Asterisk box that receives the call. Can I do that with Transfer()? Is there another way to do a SIP REFER and include some data with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 choices

1) do transfer to sip with number like sip/ID:number@other_host

After that parse id by using CUT function on destination

2) transfer to dialplan Local channel,  after that add any header you want using SipAddHeader

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but for 2) I would Transfer(Local/ext@context), then SIPAddHeader(X-ID: myid), then Dial(...). Doesn't that keep the call routing through this server? I'd like to transfer it to the other box and have this one be done with it.

Comment: Transfer exclude current server only if you do not answered call and type is sip. But you always can allow reinvite.

Comment: other solution is use sipmessage or jabber, store message in db on other side, after that transfer.

Comment: If I use SipAddHeader and then Dial() from server1 to server2, the call is still routed through server1 (it will still process the hangup, for instance). A Transfer() from server1 to server2 leaves server1 out of it and is cleaner. Is there a SipAddHeader for transfers?

Comment: That will depend of destination server and directmedia/canreinvite options. There are no sip add header for transfer. There are some variables that can be set in channel for outbound channel like codec preference, but i not think transfer will do somethign like that. Transfer command on sip (not asnwered) will do Redirect sip message. Not INVITE message. For more info read/update channels/chan_sip.c